# Вывод списка имён файлов, имеющих заданное расширение

Tags: bash, поиск, расширения

> Напишите скрипт, выводящий следующую информацию: имена всех файлов, оканчивающихся на указанное пользователем расширение, в текущем и вложенных каталогах;

Я написал

```
#!bin/bash
find $directory -iname "*.txt"
```

Во время запуска скрипта расширение должен вводить пользователь.
Помогите, пожалуйста
как получить в баш аргумент командной строки[переданный пользователем]

Comment: чтобы вопрос мог бы помочь большему кругу людей, сфокусируйте его на конкретной проблеме (упомянув исходную задачу только для контекста). К примеру, *«как получить в баш аргумент командной строки[переданный пользователем]»*

Answer (score 1):

Для обработки пользовательского ввода в Bash используется команда read. В нижеследующем примере выводится приглашение и запрашивается ввод строки, которая сохраняется в переменной с названием ext.

```
read -e -p "Укажите расширение: " ext
```

Затем содержимое переменной можно будет использовать для поиска файлов утилитой find.

```
find . -name "*.$ext"
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ @mymedia, но когда напишу расширение то покажет все файлы с разными расширениями?  А нужно только те файлы, который указан их расширения.